# Git submodule update when pulling changes

Tags: git, git-submodules, githooks

How do I configure git to automatically change submodules to their committed state, when doing a git pull?

**Here is what happens for me:**

Changes in a submodule are pulled, added, committed and pushed by someone else.
I do a git pull and have all the changed files, but my submodules remain in my local state. They now show up as modified files in git status, since my version differs from the current.

This is easily rectified by a git submodule update, but still, this behaviour is stupid and never what I would ever possibly want.

If I forget to do a git submodule update, e.g. because I was unaware, that what I pulled contained a change, submodule changes don't apply. Worse even, since they are now changes a quick commit could accidentally revert the update to the submodule.

**Here is what I want:**

When I do git pull, any changed submodules will be changed to the version committed. Initialising added submodules would be a bonus, but I'm not greedy.

Is there some great git config entry I can do to change this behaviour, or is my only option to trigger the git submodule update in hooks?

I'm new to the latter, so I would like to avoid it.

Comment: I found the following as an alias:
    pullall = "!f(){ git pull \"$@\" && git submodule update --init --recursive; }; f"
Any opinions?